# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError spark-submit in yarn cluster mode, cluster being setup using Ambari

Tags: hadoop-yarn, ambari, spark-submit

I'm using the spark-submit command as below:

```
spark-submit --class com.example.hdfs.spark.RawDataAdapter --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --jars /home/hadoop/emr/deployment/server/emr-core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar home/hadoop/emr-spark-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar hdfs://111.11.11.111:8020/user/hdfsinputfile.zip 8000
```

However, it gives me the error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/example/emr/parser/IParser3. Though the IParser3.class is present in emr-core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar. I don't understand why it throws that error. I tried several ways but couldn't succeed. How can I resolve this?

I am able to run the same command in client mode and also as a standalone spark application. Getting this error only when in yarn cluster mode.

> Exception from container-launch. Container id: container_e37_1526066605784_0014_02_000001 Exit code: 15 Container exited with a non-zero exit code 15. Error file: prelaunch.err. Last 4096 bytes of prelaunch.err : Last 4096 bytes of stderr : g.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763) at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:642) at com.example.hdfs.spark.utils.SimpleClassLoader.loadJarFile(SimpleClassLoader.java:126) at com.example.hdfs.spark.utils.SimpleClassLoader.(SimpleClassLoader.java:38) at com.example.hdfs.spark.input RawInputFormat.loadPlugins(RawInputFormat.java:71) at com.example.hdfs.spark.RawDataAdapter.run(RawDataAdapter.java:54) at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76) at com.example.hdfs.spark.RawDataAdapter.main(RawDataAdapter.java:33) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$anon$3.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:646) 18/05/14 14:00:13 ERROR ApplicationMaster: Uncaught exception: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult: at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:205) at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.runDriver(ApplicationMaster.scala:423) at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:282) at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$anonfun$main$1.apply$mcV$sp(ApplicationMaster.scala:768) at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$anon$2.run(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:67) at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$anon$2.run(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:66) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422) at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1869) at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil.runAsSparkUser(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:66) at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$.main(ApplicationMaster.scala:766) at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.main(ApplicationMaster.scala) Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: Boxed Error at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$.resolver(Promise.scala:55) at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$.scala$concurrent$impl$Promise$resolveTry(Promise.scala:47) at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:244) at scala.concurrent.Promise$class.tryFailure(Promise.scala:112) at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryFailure(Promise.scala:153) at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$anon$3.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:664) Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/example/emr/parser/IParser3 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763) at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:642) at com.example.hdfs.spark.utils.SimpleClassLoader.findClass(SimpleClassLoader.java:152) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763) at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:642) at com.example.hdfs.spark.utils.SimpleClassLoader.loadJarFile(SimpleClassLoader.java:126) at com.example.hdfs.spark.utils.SimpleClassLoader.(SimpleClassLoader.java:38) at com.example.hdfs.spark.input.RawInputFormat.loadPlugins(RawInputFormat.java:71) at com.example.hdfs.spark.RawDataAdapter.run(RawDataAdapter.java:54) at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76) at com.example.hdfs.spark.RawDataAdapter.main(RawDataAdapter.java:33) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$anon$3.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:646) Failing this attempt. Failing the application.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from Spark Documentation :-

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html

In client mode, the driver runs in the client process, and the application master is only used for requesting resources from YARN.

In cluster mode, the Spark driver runs inside an application master process which is managed by YARN on the cluster, and the client can go away after initiating the application

So in cluster mode, the jar is executed on any available node so , so you can try these 2 ways :-

1) Copy the dependency jar to each node .

2) You can try to copy the jar to Distributed (HDFS system) and then use it .

For more details you can have a look into :

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#advanced-dependency-management

Comment: I tried all the options that you provided already. Copied the jar on all the nodes as well as HDFS. Actually it is able to find the jar but not one particular class by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/example/emr/parser/IParser3 
 But IParser3.class exists in the jar. If I remove --jars /home/hadoop/emr/deployment/server/emr-core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar from the spark-submit command, it says some other class not found. When I added this option in the command, it finds that class but not IParser3.cass which is in the same jar

Comment: One more check, where did you find the jar required, was it from the /usr/lib/ dirs or from maven repos ?

Comment: @ Deepam Ram That jar is our project specific dependency jar. The java project is built using Maven. But there is no Maven installed on cluster. Does it have anything to do with that? Struggling with this error since last 3 days but couldn't find any solution.

Comment: This problem arised to me when I had some version mismatch in Hadoop cluster ( some other but same class not found exception ) . I was using different aws-sdk version than what was specified in the libs dir. Once I copied all required jars from lib into my project, it ran successfully.

Comment: @Deepam Ram Is Maven installed on your cluster? Is it necessary?